# App delay in launching the splashscreen in xamarin forms Android how to optimize the startup time

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am working on xamarin forms and I am facing issue in app delay in launching, Delay in spashscreen how to figure it out. I reduced some loading time by using "asynchronous". But it still taking 19 secs in debug and 8 secs in release mode.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    private string AppId = "6e3837aead704cb38b34985422b4d712";//Androidhockeyapp:created hockey app by using(levevagewinphne@hotmail.com)

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

            InitPlugins(bundle);

            LoadApplication(new App());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public async Task InitPlugins(Bundle bundle)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(async () =>    // by putting this Task.Run only the Activity Indicator is shown otherwise its not shown.  So we have added this.
            {
                //////hockeyApp Collect crash report
                //CrashManager.Register(this, AppId);

                //////hockeyApp User metrics
                //MetricsManager.Register(Application, AppId);

                Rg.Plugins.Popup.Popup.Init(this, bundle);

                //CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);

                BarCodes.Init(() => (Activity)Forms.Context);
                CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
                //if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
                //{
                //    Window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
                //    Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
                //    Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.ParseColor("#454546"));
                //}
            }).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using real device

Comment: When open app it takes 8 secs to take user to home page. I tried after released the apk. Splash screen will show until complete 8 secs whenever app opens

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but without any code, this is impossible to diagnose.

Comment: @Gerald Versluis above what i posted the code for mainactivity like that i made code asynchronous in MasterDetail page which is set to mainpage.

Comment: I actually need to initializes the plugins if i remove that method app will crash.

Comment: @praveenaHM- Create new blank app & check how much time taking on startup. I sure it going to take more that 8 sec. So the time now taking is reasonable.

Comment: Yes, It will take more than 8 secs in debug but in release blank project app will take only 2 secs. But in my case it is taking 8 secs

Comment: `private async void SetRoots()
{
    Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        //code here
    });
} `. Wrap your code inside this method & check.